# Storing values from for loop in Octave

Tags: for-loop, matrix, vector, octave

I was wondering if it is possible to store values from a for loop in a 1 x 100 vector row. Currently, the code generates a matrix and determines the norm of the matrix by using the eig() function.

```
for e = 1: 100
  randomMatrix = randi([0,1],100);
  eigenvalue = eig(randomMatrix)
end
```

Comment: If you change your third line to eigenvalue(e)-eig(randomMatrix) eigenvalue will be a row vector of length 100 after the for loop has ended. If you want a column vector, change the thrid line to eigenvalue(e,1)=eig(randomMatrix)

Comment: I had initially tried this, however I keep getting error: error: Q3: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 100x1)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `randomMatrix` is a 100x100 matrix, `eig` will return 100 eigenvalues, not a single value. If you want to store all these eigenvalues you will generate 100x100 elements:

```
eigenvalue = zeros(100,100);
for e = 1: 100
  randomMatrix = randi([0,1],100);
  eigenvalue(:,e) = eig(randomMatrix);
end
```

The norm of the matrix can be obtained using `norm`:

```
result = zeros(100,1);
for e = 1: 100
  randomMatrix = randi([0,1],100);
  result(e) = norm(randomMatrix);
end
```